# How to make phpcs find PHP8 errors in whole project directory?

Tags: php, phpcs

I am inside my project directory that has various files/folders and some have PHP8 fatal errors I have found when using the website (e.g. Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Non-static method), I am using the following command which I am expecting to show PHP8 compatibility errors:

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpcs . --extensions=php --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.0
```

However this is just returning 2 warnings that are for files inside `/vendor` directory, it doesn't seem to be finding the errors, I think this maybe because it's only searching through the vendor directory as I am using `./vendor/bin/phpcs` what do I need to do to make it search through all PHP files in my project directory?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the directory you want to crawl for errors. Currently you have that set to `.` which I assume would mean the current "vendor" directory. Try this:

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpcs /path/to/files/ --extensions=php --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.0
```